# Audio element refuses to fire "play" event on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio

I am developing an webview app that plays mp3's from a server.

I have the following javascript that works on iOS, but fails on Android (testing on a new LG-D160, Android 4.4.2).

On Android, the "play" event is never fired, although the "canplay" event does fire and the audio should start playing with the AudioEl1's play() method inside the "canplay" event.

Which extra step should I take to get it to play on Android?

Here is the PlayAudio() function:

```
function PlayAudio()
{    
    var AudioEl1 = new Audio();
    AudioEl1.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
        alert("loadedmetadata");
    });
    AudioEl1.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
        alert("going to play");
        AudioEl1.play();
    });
    AudioEl1.addEventListener("durationchange", function () {
        alert("durationchange");
    });
    AudioEl1.addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
        alert("loadeddata");
    });
    AudioEl1.addEventListener("progress", function () {
        alert("progress");
    });
    AudioEl1.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
        alert("started loading");
    });
    AudioEl1.addEventListener('play', function () {
        alert("playing");                                                                      
    });
    AudioEl1.src = "http://streams.greenhost.nl/cz/cz/rod/20140815-1600.mp3";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Android doesn't allow a programmer to fire the play event. It should be user initiated. So I was forced to wait for the user to click a button. At least that's how I solved this. Not ideal, but for now it works.